# How to set the width of td as float number

Tags: html, css, d3.js, floating-accuracy

Can I set width of table cell as float type?

```
td{ width:70.556123px;}
```

Or is there any other way if I can set bandWidth of scale in d3.js as integer, not float?

```
var xScale = d3.scaleBand();
xScale.domain([...]).range([...]);
```

if I output *xScale.bandWidth();* then it outputs float number, like *71.305850*

So I want to set its step or bandwidth as integer like 71.

How can I do this?

Comment: Despite the upvotes, this question makes little sense to me, I must say. First, what does the `td` have to do with the question? Second, you cannot *set* the bandwidth, it's automatically calculated according to the domain length and the range size. Finally, it is `bandwidth()`, not `bandWidth()`.

Comment: based on its bandwidth() td width is calculated, but unfortunately it's total width is slightly different. So I'm thinking this is because of round operation and I'm finding a solution now.

Comment: Anyway, you cannot set a bandwidth. If you want to convert the result of the bandwidth to an integer just use `Math.ceil`, `Math.floor`, `~~` or anything like that. Also, there is no `bandwidth()` in a linear scale, the correct result here can only be `xScale.bandwidth()  is not a function`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use floating-point numbers in CSS, there is no problem with that.

If you want your scale to return integer values, you should just use `rangeRound` instead of `range`.

Answer (score 0):

yes,you can do it but for that you have to make changes in your css.
***td{ width:70.556123%;}***